# Configuring Email Notification Oracle 12c

Tags: windows, oracle, email, smtp, alerts

I am trying to create a StoredProcedure that sends mail about the status of% of the tablespaces of an Oracle DB.
However, initially it sends me the following error (ORA-29278: transient SMTP error: 421 Service not available).
ACLs were created, permissions, communication to mail server, port, and firewall were validated, and the error no longer occurs.
The SP appears to be running correctly, but the notification mail is not being received.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr7dL.png)

Comment: Before you spend too much time debugging your procedure, have you looked into using Oracle Enterprise Manager? It has lots of pre-built alerts, including tablespace alerts. Also, you might want to use the simpler package UTL_MAIL instead of UTL_SMTP.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have the OEM so testing has already been done with
the UTL_MAIL packet, but it has the same problem as UTL_SMTP, apparently the SP works fine but we did not receive the mail. The mail server name, port, firewall has already been checked. A test was performed at the OS level (CentOS) and if the mail is received successfully, but when running the SP at the DB level, this does not happen.